# Python : Extract exact word from a url

Tags: python

I just begin to learn python from 2 days and I try to make a script that extract me some data from url and save it, but the problems is I want to extract only a specific data from a long line

EX :

> {"2019-11-19":{"period":"2019-11-19T00:00:00+00:00","uniqs":"344627","hits":"0","clicked":"4922","pay":126.52971186,"currency":"RON","subs":0},"2019-11-20":{"period":"2019-11-20T00:00:00+00:00","uniqs":"1569983","hits":"0","clicked":"15621","pay":358.43100342,"currency":"RON","subs":0},"2019-11-21":{"period":"2019-11-21T00:00:00+00:00","uniqs":"1699844","hits":"0","clicked":"16172","pay":363.15667371,"currency":"RON","subs":0},"2019-11-22":{"period":"2019-11-22T00:00:00+00:00","uniqs":"1779319","hits":"0","clicked":"17865","pay":384.67092962,"currency":"RON","subs":0},"2019-11-23":{"period":"2019-11-23T00:00:00+00:00","uniqs":"1825346","hits":"0","clicked":"17740","pay":356.72833095,"currency":"RON","subs":0},"2019-11-24":{"period":"2019-11-24T00:00:00+00:00","uniqs":"1732639","hits":"0","clicked":"16870","pay":308.4201041,"currency":"RON","subs":0},"2019-11-25":{"period":"2019-11-25T00:00:00+00:00","uniqs":"1826060","hits":"0","clicked":"17991","pay":346.29137133,"currency":"RON","subs":0},"2019-11-26":{"period":"2019-11-26T00:00:00+00:00","uniqs":"1873961","hits":"0","clicked":"18645","pay":379.17652358,"currency":"RON","subs":0},"2019-11-27":{"period":"2019-11-27T00:00:00+00:00","uniqs":"1734207","hits":"0","clicked":"16187","pay":251.91152953,"currency":"RON","subs":0},"2019-11-28":{"period":"2019-11-28T00:00:00+00:00","uniqs":"1611611","hits":"0","clicked":"12056","pay":158.96447829,"currency":"RON","subs":0},"2019-11-29":{"period":"2019-11-29T00:00:00+00:00","uniqs":"712011","hits":"0","clicked":"6242","pay":85.70053418,"currency":"RON","subs":0},"2019-11-30":{"period":"2019-11-30T00:00:00+00:00","uniqs":"47957","hits":"0","clicked":"427","pay":8.32775435,"currency":"RON","subs":0},"2019-12-01":{"period":"2019-12-01T00:00:00+00:00","uniqs":"1268892","hits":"0","clicked":"11779","pay":217.42321168,"currency":"RON","subs":0},"2019-12-02":{"period":"2019-12-02T00:00:00+00:00","uniqs":"1130724","hits":"0","clicked":"10694","pay":195.44476902,"currency":"RON","subs":0},"2019-12-03":{"period":"2019-12-03T00:00:00+00:00","uniqs":"1058965","hits":"0","clicked":"8123","pay":151.05243751,"currency":"RON","subs":0},"2019-12-04":{"period":"2019-12-04T00:00:00+00:00","uniqs":"1228326","hits":"0","clicked":"12230","pay":230.84154581,"currency":"RON","subs":0},"2019-12-05":{"period":"2019-12-05T00:00:00+00:00","uniqs":"1181029","hits":"0","clicked":"11467","pay":196.21644271,"currency":"RON","subs":0},"2019-12-06":{"period":"2019-12-06T00:00:00+00:00","uniqs":"951828","hits":"0","clicked":"9379","pay":153.35155293,"currency":"RON","subs":0},"2019-12-07":{"period":"2019-12-07T00:00:00+00:00","uniqs":"1172156","hits":"0","clicked":"11776","pay":181.65819439,"currency":"RON","subs":0},"2019-12-08":{"period":"2019-12-08T00:00:00+00:00","uniqs":"912109","hits":"0","clicked":"9240","pay":147.6364827,"currency":"RON","subs":0}}

I try to extract the after "pay": and save it to a file, after that i write the code that will calculate the amount and give me the result :D for this i worked 1 day :D

i use this code to extract and save the data from link :

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
url1 = 'http://link.com'
page = uReq(url1).read().decode()
f = open("dataNEW.txt", "w")
f.write(page)
f.close()
```

but the problem is it write me all details there, I want to save only what is after pay.

Comment: This looks like a JSON document. It would be much easier if you just parse it using `json` (or use the `requests` library that automatically does that for you). Also, which `pay` are you after? There is a separate `pay` key for each subdictionary.

Comment: I try to extract all pay from that url in the future it will be more

Comment: Can you give an example of your expected output? Do you want to see a column of numbers in `dataNEW.txt` only?

Comment: 126.52971186
358.43100342
363.15667371
384.67092962
356.72833095
308.4201041 line by line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That string is in JSON format that can be easily converted to a Python data structure using the `json` package. Her is an example:

```
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq

url1 = 'http://link.com'
page = uReq(url1).read().decode()
data = json.loads(page)
with open("dataNEW.txt", "w") as f:
    for sub_dict in data.values():
        f.write("{}\n".format(sub_dict["pay"]))
```

Your `dataNEW.txt` should then look like the following:

```
358.43100342
363.15667371
384.67092962
356.72833095
126.52971186
346.29137133
379.17652358
251.91152953
158.96447829
85.70053418
8.32775435
147.6364827
153.35155293
181.65819439
308.4201041
196.21644271
230.84154581
151.05243751
195.44476902
217.42321168
```

Comment: SUPERB !!!!!!!!!!!! thank you !!!!!! I works flawless with my other part of script :D I hope in few years that I can answer also to other ppl that put question here